# Postback event of the update panel, reflecting the current state of controls in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have Update panel control. In which there are two radio buttons & 2 div's. when we click on the radio button respective div should be displayed. & by default 1 of those button is checked and the respective div is displayed.

Problem:
when the default button is selected, the div is displayed properly, but when I select another button, in keeps the page inactive for a minute or any event is occurred like click or so,then the default buttons respective div is displayed again,instead of the selected one's.

Code:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="newUP" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

             <table>
             <tr>
              <td style="float:left; margin:0px;">
                 <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnInclude" runat="server" GroupName="Stores" Checked="true" Text="Include"/><br />
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td style="float:left; margin:0px;">
                 <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnExclude" runat="server" GroupName="Stores" Text="Exclude"/>  
               </td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <table>
               <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="divIn" id="DivIn1" runat="server" style="width:700px; display: block;">
                        DIV IN TEXT
                  </div>
              </td>
              <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="divEx" id="DivEx1" runat="server" style="width:700px; display: none;">            DIV EX TEXT 
                   </div>
               </td>
              </tr>    

            </table>
            </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript:

```
function enableDisableDiv()
{
  if (document.getElementById("<%=rbtnInclude.ClientID %>").checked)
        {
            $(".divIn").show();
            $(".divEx").hide();

        }
  if (document.getElementById("<%=rbtnExclude.ClientID %>").checked)
        {
            $(".divIn").hide();
            $(".divEx").show();

        }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
        rbtnInclude.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: enableDisableDiv();");
        rbtnExclude.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: enableDisableDiv();");
        }
```

*Edit:* This panel is nested into the another update panel too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add little script block under  enableDisableDiv() function.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function enableDisableDiv()
{
     //Do your stuff
}

function pageLoad() {
    enableDisableDiv()
}

</script>
```